# PSQL prevent "COMMENT ON" on the DB dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump

We are migrating some products, one of the steps is to migrate the product databases.

I have steps to

- export the existing DB  `pg_dump --no-owner --clean --blobs --no-privileges -U dbuser old_dbname -f bkpfile.sql`
- import the dump to a different DB `psql -U dbuser2 new_dbname -f bkpfile.sql`

The problem is the old database contains statement `COMMENT ON DATABASE old_dbname IS 'Rxxxxx';`

The new DB user must not have permissions on the old database and imho it's not good to refer the old database name anyway in the dump.

Is there a way to create a complete DB dump without the `COMMENT ON DATABASE` statement?

Edit:

PostgreSQL 9.6
Steps to reproduce:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
COMMENT ON DATABASE testdb IS 'some comment';
CREATE TABLE xx (id int);
```

and then dump the database, the dump contains reference to the database name `COMMENT ON DATABASE testdb IS 'some comment';` which prevents importing the backup to a new database

```
pg_dump --no-owner --clean --blobs --no-privileges testdb
```

We could manually remove the comment statement or filter the comment using different tools (grep), but manual intervention or text-based filtering on top of the backup could cause data corruption.

Comment: If you don't want the dump to refer to the database, you'll have to omit the `--create` option.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I didn't use any `create` option..  And we need to create schema anyway somehow.. or you mean - the comment is part of the schema?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. But without `--create` you will never get a `COMMENT ON DATABASE` in the dump.

Comment: What PostgreSQL version is that? Is it normal PostgreSQL or some fork? Can you come up with a simple reproducer?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated the question with the DB version and reproducing steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment is only dumped in PostgreSQL versions below v11. See this entry in the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html):

> pg_dump and pg_restore, without `--create`, no longer dump/restore database-level comments and security labels; those are now treated as properties of the database.

9.6 will go out of support soon anyway, so this is a good opportunity to upgrade.